# Use BLAST SRA function with R

Tags: r, blast, ncbi

I'm an R noob, but can I control the SRA function in NCBI BLAST from command line in R? The NCBI website is notoriously unreliable, and I'd like to be able to manage batches of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ape and BoSSA packages together should do what you want. BoSSA has a blast function that calls the blast API and uses the DNAbin format from ape.